# How can I use subquery in DDL? Question related to Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ddl

I want to know, is it possible and if it possible, then I need a few examples about.
In which statement I can do this operation? I know about subquery in Create statement, but I have no information about Drop, Alter and Truncate. 
Please help me with exmples. Thanks in advance. 
Also, I need to know about subquery in Group by clause. Is it possible as well?

Comment: Hello Tgy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an actual example of the problem that you are trying to solve, otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: I think `create table as ...` is the only DDL that will allow "sub-queries".

Comment: What effect would you expect a subquery to have in other DDL? You can't partially alter or drop an object. Or are you trying to get the object name from a subquery - which you can't do, even with `create`?

Comment: Yes i want select name of table which need to drop and drop this table in th same query. I need the answer to this question because i want to pass exam and on exam questions there are some questions like this.